# MonoDevelop not running after installation of a newer version of mono

Tags: ubuntu, mono, monodevelop

After installing a newer version of mono (4.0.1) on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS i am getting an exception on running MonoDevelop

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred.
  at MonoDevelop.Startup.MonoDevelopMain.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred.
  at MonoDevelop.Startup.MonoDevelopMain.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I have tried to reinstall MonoDevelop but nothing changed.
May be some assemblies are missing.

How can i solve that ? If necessary i can provide more information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you rollback the version of Mono does it work?  You are using the current version of MonoDevelop correct?

Comment: I didn't try to rollback the version of mono because i need it at the moment. Yes i'm using the current verion of MonoDevelop installed from Ubuntu Software Center. But i do not exclude that i probably did something wrong when i installed mono 4.0.1 but it seems working well.

Comment: You need to try and roll back the version of  Mono, this might be an incompatibility with MonoDevelop and Mono 4.0.1 if that's the case not much you can do about it.

Comment: Ok. I will try and give you a feedback.

Comment: I tried to rollback and nothing changed.

Comment: The next step would be to uninstall installations then reinstall both installations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By suggestion of Ramhound, i resolved the problem by uninstalling both mono and MonoDevelop then i installed first MonoDevelop then mono, i don't know if the order matters but perhaps it matters because MonoDevelop didn't like something when i intalled a newer version of mono and even reinstalling of MonoDevelop didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

I've tracked down the issue to missing glib-sharp
and resolved it by installing package gtk-sharp2-complete (FC 21)